# Median of n normal distributions

Tags: probability, median

I have the following problem: I would like to know the distribution of $\mathrm{Med}[X1,\ldots,Xn]$, where $X1,\ldots,Xn$ are standard normal distributions $N(0,1)$. I know that one should consider two cases for odd and even $n$.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Variance might help. So in your example of a standard normal distribution with large $n$ then about $\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2n}}$

Comment: We all know what the median of a distribution is, but how do you define the median of $n$ real numbers, especially when $n$ is not odd?

Comment: In any case, look at the "median theorem" [here](http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/BrownClasses/162/Handouts/MedianThm04.pdf)

Comment: I'm specifically interested in the case of "small" n, say, 5 or 10 or sth. I know the formula for the distribution of order statistics, but somehow I've found  it hard to perform the integrals occuring there. As for what I mean by the median of n real numbers - it's the (n+1)/2th largest number  (in case of odd n)